# How to add comments in build.prop file?

Tags: customization

If it differs across Android versions, provide answer specifically for KitKat and Lollipop.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just precede your comments with the `#` character.

```
# this is a comment
ro.lcd_density=160    # this is another comment
```